# Обтекание <div> или отображение по центру, в зависимости от размера экрана

Tags: css, bootstrap, flexbox

Использую Bootstrap-4 и Fancybox.

У меня есть код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-left text-justify d-inline-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <h1>Стела Откровения</h1>
        <p>Фивы, XXVI династия, оштукатуренное дерево, 31 x 51,5 см., N666 в каталоге музея Булака, Каир (теперь в Египетском музее N9422, Каир).

        <div class="m-4 align-self-center">
            <a href="/img/stelefnt.jpg" data-fancybox data-caption="Стела Откровения">
               <div class="thumbnail"><img src="/img/stelefnt.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        Сверху изображена богиня неба, Нут (Нуит), согнувшаяся подобно 
        своду, руками и ногами она касается земли. Непосредственно под ней — 
        крылатый солнечный диск (Гор Бехдетский, Хадит)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Меня устраивает то, как это отображается на малых устройствах -  **c картинкой по центру**. Я хочу что бы **на экране настольного компьютера данный  c картинкой отображался не по центру, но был прижат либо к левому краю страницы, либо к правому (на мой выбор), а текст обтекал его**.
Мне не принципиально использовать flexbox, я только осваиваюсь в Bootstrap и это единственный способ, который я пока нашёл для отображения  по центру.

Answer (score 0):

Для разного позиционирования элементов в зависимости от размеров экарана, ты можешь использоваь медиазапросы https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/ или переопределять классы бутсрапа так, чтобы при определенном размере экрана твой блок прижимался к караю.